# Standard form of parametric equation of Parabola

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

Standard parametric equations of a parabola of the form $y^2=4ax$ are:
$$
x(t)=at^2\\
y(t)=2at
$$
which is fine since it can be easily verified. But is there any reason or advantage of making such a choice in the parametric equation of parabola ?

Comment: You've got $x(t), y(t)$ the wrong way round.

Comment: Advantage compared to which other choice ? [By the way, I see nothing "standard" here.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust i understand we are free to make appropriate choice of parameters. but the above form is what usually used as the parametric form of the given parabola. So i was wondering is there any particular reason beyond simplicity of the equation?

Comment: @ss1729: I have rarely seen this form and you don't answer: what are the alternatives ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust what if i simply put $y(t)=t$ and $x(t)=\frac{t^2}{4a}$

Comment: @YvesDaoust and also, $2at$ is the derivative of $at^2$, so i was thinking is there anything more about such a choice

Comment: IMO all forms $x=at,y=bt^2$ are virtually equivalent. I don't see an advantage of having $x=\dot y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Cartesian form equation for the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is significant because $a$ is the focal length, the focus of the parabola is $(a,0)$ and also because $4a$ is the length of the *latus rectum*.

For this parabola, the standard parametric equation $(at^2, 2at)$  is probably the simplest  possible as it does not contain fractions. Other possibilities are $\left(\frac {t^2}{4a} , t\right), \left(\frac {t^2}a, 2t\right)$, which are not as neat.

---

Another example of a possible parametric equation is $\big(4a\sin t, 2a(1-\cos 2t)\big)$.

Comment: thnx. i understand there s nothing standard in this particular form since we are free to choose the parameter as long as it satisfies the equation of the parabola. my doubt was avoiding fraction to make it simple is the only reason for such a choice ?

Comment: That's only my conjecture. Hopefully it's a logical one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard parametrization.

A parametrization is beneficial if the parameter has an extra or particular  geometrical or physical significance.

The given parametrization has focal length $a$. Differentiating $x$ wrt $y$ through $t,$ it can be appreciated that $t$ also represents tangent of angle which the  tangent of parabola ( axis on $x$ axis) makes to the $y$ axis. It is also simple, algebraically.

EDIT1:

Another direct (unparametrized) *oblique axes* form with two branches with constants $ {(m,h,k)} $ is:

$$y=  m x \pm \sqrt{m x h + k^2}$$